How to Use Part of a TikZ Style Defined Globally in LaTeX?
I want to define a TikZ style globally at the beginning of my document and use its properties throughout the document. However, I also want to extract and use only specific parts of the style, such as just the color, in certain places.
For example, let’s say I define a style for a curve called measurements with the following properties:
Color: red
Line width: thin
Line type: dashed
Marker: rectangle
Now, I want to:

Use the full measurements style for some curves.

Use only the red color from measurements for other elements.


Is there a way to define a comprehensive TikZ style and selectively apply part of its definition?
Here’s a minimal working example (MWE):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Global style definition
\tikzset{
  measurements/.style = {
    red,
    thin,
    dashed,
    mark=rectangle
  }
}

\begin{document}

% Full style usage
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[measurements] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Attempt to use only the color from `measurements`
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,-1) (2,0)}; % Hardcoded color
  % I would like to use something like [measurements.color] here
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Desired Outcome:
I want to avoid hardcoding the color (red) again when using it in other parts of the document. Instead, I’d like to reference the color from the measurements style directly.
Is this possible in TikZ, or is there another approach to achieve this flexibility?

measurements/color/.style=red, measurements/linewidth/.style=thin, measurements/linestyle/.style=dashed, measurements/mark/.style=rectangle, measurements/.style={measurements/color, measurements/linewidth, measurements/linestyle, measurements/mark} would allow you something like that. Of course, you can always measurement/.append style=blue which would break this but as long as you use those styles properly … (there's no automatic measurements key that applies all keys in this path). There's also key filtering but that's a bit more complex.

For colours specifically, I would use aliases which you define in the preamble and use throughout, both in setting up tikz style and in any other place you need to adhere to a global colour palette.
For example,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Global style definition
\colorlet{mycolour}{red}
\tikzset{
  measurements/.style = {
    mycolour,
    thin,
    dashed,
    mark=rectangle
  }
}

\begin{document}

% Full style usage
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[measurements] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[mycolour] plot coordinates {(0,0) (1,-1) (2,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\textcolor{mycolour}{Important!} Less important \dots.

\end{document}

Unlike a tikz style, you can use this easily in other elements such as headers, text etc. If you change your mind about red, you need only alter a single word in the preamble.
